# Looking for 80's series or movie about programmable short-term memory

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find this again has been bugging me for years. Here's what I remember:

- probably a TV series, but could also be a movie/mini-series
- should have been around in the 80's (saw it around 1978-1985)
- about an experimental/military group that can "upload" short-term memories using Alpha(?) waves. (no, it's not the Matrix)
- these memories last exactly a specific time (60 minutes?), then he forgets everything again
- they use this technology to feed their guy/agent with vital knowledge about missions (to help others?)
- one example would be how to fly a helicopter (yes, I'm *certain* it's not the Matrix :-P

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: Note: It's quite likely the country of origin is non-US/non-English, which might explain why it's difficult to find more info on this (in Germany, all movies and series are dubbed, so it's impossible to tell)

Comment: It could also have been that the guy was brain damaged because of an accident, and he had lost his complete memory, and these short-time boosts were the only way he could function again. After the 60 minutes he would once again lose his complete memory. Not sure which variant it was.

Comment: Johnny Mnemonic?

Comment: No, much older. Thanks, though.

Comment: Joe 90 seems pretty unlikely, as I'm sure you would have remembered it as a puppet show and with a young boy protagonist, but I guess it's still vaguely related...

Comment: I remember seeing this.  The guy was in an accident or something and had amnesia, creating a blank slate for them to imprint memories on.  I think memories would last 24 hours or so.  What he learned normally he'd remember, what he learned by imprint would fade - and not slowly, but all at once.  I'm pretty sure there was a sequence where he had to drive a race car and they had to imprint the memories by remote or something and later he was racing to escape and had to get clear before his race car driving memories went away.  It was a pilot that never made it to series.

Comment: Yes, I have been trying to remember this myself. The race car driver sequence I think happened like he posed as a telephone worker and went up the pole and they programmed him to drive.

Comment: I remember seeing some episodes of this serie in the 80's, each episode was based on a specific skill set (helicopter pilot, martial artist,...). I believe it was in the same universe as the serie "six million dollars man"", the boss of the main character was the boss of lee major in six million dollar man.

Comment: Are you **sure** it isn't the Matrix?  ;-)

Answer (score 7):

This has been bugging me for a while because I remember this show vividly AND I finally found it: [The Ultimate Impostor](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the-ultimate-impostor-the-72-hour-dead-line/)

bonus: it stars Erin Gray!

He's a spy who had his memory erased by the Russians and now they can program him with knowledge but it only lasts 72 hours.

@user13649: The Oscar Goldman reference above was a show called The Delphi Bureau - about a guy with a photographic memory.

Answer (score 4):

And here is the race car scene.

You have no idea how long I have wanted to know the answer to this.